# Can I write the output the of time difference command to a file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection, time

Can I write the output of the time difference command to a file?

For example, I tried:

```
$ time foo.sh > bar.txt
```

But it only gives the output of foo.sh to bar.txt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In many shells including `ksh`, `zsh` and `bash`, `time` is a keyword and is used to time pipelines.

```
time foo | bar
```

Will time both the `foo` and `bar` commands (`zsh` will show you the breakdown). It reports it on the shell's stderr.

```
time foo.sh > bar.txt
```

Will tell you the time needed to open `bar.txt` and run `foo.sh`.

If you want to redirect `time`'s output, you need to redirect `stderr` in the context where `time` is started like:

```
{ time foo.sh; } 2> bar.txt
```

This:

```
2> bar.txt time foo.sh
```

works as well but with `ksh93` and `bash`, because it's not in first position, `time` is not recognised as a keyword, so the `time` *command* is used instead (you'll probably notice the different output format, and it doesn't time pipelines).

Note that both would redirect both the output of time and the errors of `foo.sh` to `bar.txt`. If you only want the time output, you'd need:

```
{ time foo.sh 2>&3 3>&-; } 3>&2 2> bar.txt
```

Note that POSIX doesn't specify whether `time` behaves as a keyword or builtin (whether it times pipelines or single commands). So to be portable (in case you want to use it in a `sh` script which you want portable to different Unix-like systems), you should probably write it:

```
command time -p foo.sh 2> bar.txt
```

Note that you can't time functions or builtins or pipelines or redirect `foo.sh` errors separately there unless you start a separate shell as in:

```
command time -p sh -c 'f() { blah; }; f | cat'
```

But that means the timing will also include the startup time of that extra `sh`.

Answer (score 3):

`/usr/bin/time` outputs to `stderr`, so you will need to redirect that.

```
/usr/bin/time foo.sh 2>bar.txt
```

If you use bash' `time` builtin, you need to write it differently:

```
(time ls) 2>bar.txt
```

Alternatively, GNU `time` supports an `--output` argument:

```
/usr/bin/time --output bar.txt foo.sh
```

Comment: Hmm, my time doesn't have the output argument and the 2>bar.txt didn't work.

Comment: What version do you have? GNU Time is `/usr/bin/time -V`. There is also the time command built into bash.

Comment: It's old enough that it doesn't support that argument... I'll look for an update

Comment: That first example didn't work for me either on a Fedora 14 laptop. I don't think it has to do with time, it's how we're piping the output. If you change it to `(time ls) 2>bar.txt` it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Not all versions of time support the -o and --output arguments.

You will want to run the command like this:

```
(time script.sh) 1> /dev/null 2> /tmp/logFile
```

This will put the output of script.sh into /dev/null and the results to /tmp/logFile.

If you want both STDERR and STDOUT to go to the log file you can run it like this:

```
(time script.sh) &> /tmp/logFile
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the output of `ls` and the output of `time` in the file:

```
(time ls) &> log
```

To get just the output of `time` in the file:

```
(time ls) 2> log
```